# How to check if something is in 2 lists with python

Tags: python, list, compare, set

First of all, i gotta say this is the code for a chat bot. I am giving the bot a list of words to track and then i'm splitting all messages in the room. Now i need to make something like:

```
IF any word from my list is IN message.body THEN do something.
```

But all attemps failed, this is my code.

```
  leyendotracker = open("listas\eltracker.txt", "r") #Open file with tracker words
  buffertracker = leyendotracker.read() #Read words and save them in a variable
  leyendotracker.close() #Close file
  s1tracker = set(message.body.split()) #Set the messages in chat as a Set
  s2tracker = set(buffertracker) #Set the variable with words from file as a Set
  if s2tracker in s1tracker: #Check if any word from the file is in the message from chat.
    print("[TRACKER - "+user.name+" said: "+message.body)
```

That should work in theory, however i don't fully understand how Sets works and i just googled my problem and converted my lists (yes, both are lists, not dicts) into Sets hoping that would fix the problem. Nevertheless, i surrender after 1 hour of dealing with this problem.

What am i missing?
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in filter function:

```
>>> hot_words = ["spam", "eggs"]
>>> message_body = "Oh boy, my favourite! spam, spam, spam, eggs and spam"
>>> matching_words = filter(lambda word: word in hot_words, message_body.split())
>>> matching_words
['eggs', 'spam']
>>> message_body = "No, I'd rather just egg and bacon"
>>> matching_words = filter(lambda word: word in hot_words, message_body.split())
>>> matching_words
[]
```

Splitting the string obviously turns it into a list of individual words, and the built-in 'filter' takes a lambda function as an argument which should returns true or false as to whether the item passed to it, should be included in the result set.

**Update** - To answer the question that I *think* you're asking in your comment:
After the line:

```
trackeado = filter(lambda word: word in buffertracker, message.body.split())
```

traceado should be a list containing the words in a message that match your list of words.  Essentially, you just need to check whether or not that list has a 0 length or not:

```
if len(trackeado) > 0:
    # Do something
```

**Update update** - Ah, I've just realised that your buffertracker isn't a list, it's just a long string read in from a file.  In my example, hot_words is a list of individual words that you're looking for.  Depending on how your file is formatted, you'll need to do something to it, to turn it into a list.

e.g. if your file is a comma-separated list of words, do this:

```
>>> words = buffer tracker.split(',')
>>> trackeado = filter(lambda word: word in words, message.body.split())
>>> if len(trackeado) > 0:
...     print "found"
```

Comment: uhm.... tried this 3 lines of code: #1    trackeado = filter(lambda word: word in buffertracker, message.body.split()) #2 if not trackeado == None: #3 print("Test") However it was saving everything, ignoring the words in my list.

Comment: Wait, i just did re-read this, should i put IF true instead If not None?

Comment: Always getting: <filter object at 0x03369DF0>

Comment: After your update update all i am getting is: TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len() - Edit, i am using 3.3.2 python, if matters.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, righto, yes thanks, it matters :) In python 3 the filter function returns a generator, not a list.  You can just turn your generator INTO a list by doing: list(trackeado)

Comment: Ok let me check... uhm where, here? if len(list(trackeado)) > 0: - - -Update: Oh my god, finally! 10 hours later... this works! Thank you very much :D (I learned something and you were very helpful :D)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to see if there is an [intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) between sets:

> intersection(other, ...)
>
> set & other & ...
>
> Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

```
if s2tracker & s1tracker:
    # do smth
```

Comment: Tried that and now works... randomly, gives me no error but weird behavior. My list is: ["Bot", "bot", "saelyth", "sael", " sae ", " sae", "Sael", " Sae ", "elyth"] however it ignores my list and saves the text each time someone writes something with a word "a" for example: this sentence a would be saved

Comment: @Saelyth may be this is because you are splitting words by just space..what about punctuation?

Comment: uhm, You mean in the message.body.split()? I'm not sure, if i print that one with str(message.body.split()) it gives me this result ['!test', 'this', 'sentence', 'as', 'example'] So... it shouldn't matter that i split with spaces, right?

Comment: Right, looks ok on this example. Then, what about the words from the file - could you print them and see if there is nothing wrong, like new-line chars at the end?

Comment: And this is why i am in StackOverflow, i don't see what is wrong neither :( Here are the the prints: http://prntscr.com/1pa1sm

Comment: ok Solution found in the Answer from @David-Downes :D Thanks for the help anyway.